# Sum of two random variables independent

Tags: probability, random-variable, descriptive-statistics

Let's say that T1, T2, T3 are random variables, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent and $T_3=T_1+T_2$.
Are $T_3$ and $T_2$ independent? Intuitively, i'd say no. However I cannot find a proof of it.

Comment: Not so silly. I think the continuous  needs to be handled differently from what we have seen so far.

Comment: When all three variables are continuous for T_3 to be independent of T_2 i P[ T_3<=x and T_2<=y]  =P[T_3<=x ] P[T_2<=y] for any choice of x and y.  So to prove dependence you need to find an x and a y where the relationship does not hold.  Keep in mind that you can substitute T_3 -T_1 for T_2.  The reason I am only sketching an approach is because I haven't been able to follow this through rigorously yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_3$ and $T_2$ are not independent. Since $T_3=T_1+T_2$,  $E(T_3) = E(T_1) + E(T_2)$. If $T_3$ and $T_2$ were independent,  it would have to be true that for any a, $E(T_3 | T_2=a) = E(T_3) = E(T_1) + E(T_2)$.
But actually, $E(T_3 | T_2=a) = E(T_1) + a$.

Comment: That is  what I was planning to use. if T_2 is discrete.and not a constant. It doesn't cover the continuous case though.

Comment: This is also true for continuous $T_2$ which is not constant.. It is still possible to make a choice of $T_2$   ( $T_2 = a$ ) and evaluate $E(T_3 | T_2=a)$

Comment: Note that if T_2 is constant then a =E(T_2) in the discrete case.

Comment: No. If $T_2$ is discrete, we can still evaluate $E(T_3 | T_2=a)$  for every possible value of $T_2$

Comment: My issue is that in the continuous case P(T_2=a) =0 for any fixed a.

Comment: In the continuous case,  this is a statement about the probability density function.  Yes,  the probability of hitting exactly any value is zero,  but the probability density is not zero for all values.

Comment: I think you need to show that the use of conditional expectation works like the way you suggest.  What exactly are you doing to replace T_2=a with? It is not sufficient to simply say use the probability density. To use the probability density you need to apply a limiting process for an interval about a to have it length go to 0.

Comment: I think this does hold in the case that T1 and T2 are gamma distributed?